# encapsulation of subclasses from a constructor in C#

Tags: c#, encapsulation

I am sorry if the question isn't too clear, but I did'nt know
how else to phrase it.

I am attempting to create a card game which contains the following classes
The suits are Red, Blue, Green, and Yellow and depending on the suit
the value is the product of the cards number and the suit multiplier

red = 1

blue = 2

green = 3

yellow = 4

```
abstract class Card;

public class Deck
{
    private List<Card> deckList;
}

public class RedCard : Card, suit 
{
    private int number;

    public int Getvalue()
    {
        return number;
    }
}

interface suit
{
    int GetValue();
}
```

is there a way to encapsulate the Card subclasses so
that the Deck constructor does not need to know what
kind of cards can be added to the deck.
The aim is to make sure that the Deck class does not need
to be altered if I add another suit/card subclass in the future

Comment: Why are you using inheritance for this? It makes the whole overly complex. And complexity is both less performant and more difficult to maintain. Normally the cardColor would be an enum.

Comment: @jHBonarius 
You make a good point, enums would make it all much easier
I suppose the fact that all the recent work done in this class (software design)
has focused on inheritance and interfaces, simply left me in that mindset, so
it seemed like the most natural way to go.

Comment: Common pitfall. However, inheritance is just 'a' tool in the shed. It's not always the best tool for the job. (Actual more often: not at all). But it all depends on what you are trying to achieve. You're explanation and example is too simple maybe

Comment: It still begs the question though how to encapsulate this infomation so that
the deck class doesn't need to know about the suit for it to construct the deckList.
I should be able to add more suits without making alterations to the Deck class in
anyway.

Comment: We both edited at the same time. We need more info to be able to help. And maybe this is a question for Software Engineering stack overflow or Code Review SO. Open closed/loose coupling is indeed good practice.  But don't over engineer

Comment: I think I got it, my idea is to simply iterate over the enum list to get the required number over cards. If I had more colors through the enum list that should not impact the deck class. 
Thanks so much for helping me put everything into perspective.

Comment: I can't understand your question, because now deck can add any card instance into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about this in real world terms, you have a `Deck` that has instances of `Card` in it. The types of attributes or physical *properties* of the cards in the deck are all the same, they all have a `Suit` and a `Number` and in your business case they all have a `Value` as well. From a structural point of view they are identical, all that changes are the values for each of the *properties*.

If every *Card* has the same attributes, and the same behaviours, then there is no reason to create further sub-classes or even interfaces of these *Cards*.

In software design, we use inheritance and composition (Interfaces) to add attributes and behaviours to the base implementation; or to change existing behaviours. It is an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) to inherit from a *Card* just to change the values of the attributes and doing so can elad to confusion down the track. You really need to separate the concept of *structure* vs *content*. If the structure and beahviour

On top of this you have defined a list of *suits* and have declared that they have specific integer values, in C# we can encapsulate such fixed lists using an `enum`.

```
public enum Suit : int
{
    Red = 1,
    Blue = 2,
    Green = 3,
    Yellow = 4
}

public class Deck
{
    private List<Card> deckList;
}

public class Card
{
    public Suit Suit { get; private set; }
    public int Number { get; private set; }

    public Card (Suit suit, int number)
    {
        this.Suit = suit;
        this.Number = number;
    }
  
    public int Value { get { return (int)Suit * Number; } }
}
```

We can now create a method to generate a deck of cards for us, based on some fixed criteria, I'll call this from the constructor for this demo:

```
public class Deck
{
    private const int LENGTH_OF_SUIT = 10;
    private List<Card> deckList = new List<Card>();
    
    public Deck()
    {
        BuildDeck();
    }

    private void BuildDeck()
    {
        foreach (Suit suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
        {
            for(int number = 1 ; number <= LENGTH_OF_SUIT; number ++)
            {
                deckList.Add(new Card(suit, number));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This simple structure is one way to encapsulates the requirements listed in the original post, you can play with this here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnhGGG

---

If the number of suits can change at runtime, then an enum is **NOT** a good fit, then you would need a class to represent the `Suit`:

```
public class Suit
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public int Value { get;set; }
}
```

But note that the `Card` class doesn't need to change much:

```
public class Card
{
    public Suit Suit { get; private set; } 
    public int Number { get; private set; } 

    public Card (Suit suit, int number)
    {
        this.Suit = suit;
        this.Number = number;
    }

    public int Value { get { return Suit.Value * Number; } }
}
```

To build the deck we would need additional information, like what suits to build:

```
public class Deck
{
    private const int LENGTH_OF_SUIT = 10;
    private List<Card> deckList = new List<Card>();
    
    public Deck(Suit[] suits)
    {
        BuildDeck(suits);
    }

    private void BuildDeck(Suit[] suits)
    {
        foreach (Suit suit in suits)
        {
            for(int number = 1 ; number <= LENGTH_OF_SUIT; number ++)
            {
                deckList.Add(new Card(suit, number));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, if we need to get all the `Cards` of a specific `Suit` we could add a method that does this for us to the `Deck`

```
public List<Card> GetCardsOfSuit(Suit suit)
{
    return deckList.Where(x => x.Suit == suit).ToList(); 
}
```

*There are many other ways to implement the same or similar logic, this is but one example.*

---

You may have started off in your learning using `Vehicle` and then created sub classes for `Car` and `MotorCycle`. Often the example is that `Vehicle` has a property for `Wheels` and the `Car` has 4 `Wheels` and the `MotorCycle` has 2.

That model alone is flawed as a learning tool, it can lead you to assume that the *reason* behind subclassing was to change the value of a fixed property. This example has been overly simplified, fundamentally there are other attributes and behaviours that give us real world, anc conceptual reasons to classify these objects into their own class definition.

It was an example devised because in the real world classification of *Cars* and *MotorCycles* separately is very logical and it is easy to comprehend that they are both types of *Vehicles*.

If we start to talk about *Color* of a `Vehicle`, then we are closer to the concept of a `Suit` of a `Card`. you can have a Red `Car` and a Red `MotorCycle`, but the color is only one of the attributes of that physical object, we do not now create a new class definition to represent `RedCar` and `RedMotorCycle`... `Red` is simply the *Value* of the `Color` *property*.

### A better inheritance example

The example of an `Animal` that has sub classes of `Bird` and `Fish` makes it easier to show the similarities (what is inherited) and the differences in the *types* of attributes and beahviours encapsulated by the class definitions:

We can have a count of eyes for all animals, and some type of animals by definition will only have a fixed number of eyes. So we can use eyes to show overriding fixed values. But it doesn't make sense to have a property on Animal to store the number of wings, because that is part of the definition that makes an animal a bird and no other type of animal will have wings at all. We wouldn't store the fact that a bird has any number of wings because **All birds have 2 wings by definition**. We would not normally even bother to record that fact in our model, because it is a constant value and not likely to be of any use to us. But *Flight* is a behaviour common to birds, but not all birds can fly! Now we can start to talk about behaviours.

In this model we will capture 2 types of real world behaviours as properties, we wont specifically add any c# *behaviours* in these definitions, but it is a better tool to enable new developers to relate these abstract c# concepts to the real world.

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Number of Eyes</summary>
    /// <remarks>Not all animals have eyes, use 0 to represent no eyes</remarks>
    public virtual int Eyes { get; set; };

    public string override ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} - Eyes:{Eyes}";
    }
}

/// <summary>Vertebrates have a spine, but are also `Chordates`, they have "Camera Eyes" that are specifically 2 eyes using lenses to focus an image.</summary>
/// <remarks>http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/1999-02/920061344.Ev.r.html#:~:text=This%20is%20the%20same%20process%20at%20work%20in,they%20retained%20the%20trait%20from%20a%20common%20ancestor.</remarks>
public class Vertebrate : Animal
{
    public override sealed int Eyes { get { return 2; } set{/*Force only 2 eyes, ignore setter*/} }
}

public class Bird : Vertebrate 
{
    /// <summary>Not all birds can fly: penguins, emus and ostriches are some examples </summary> 
    public bool CanFly { get;set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + $", CanFly :{CanFly}";
    }
}

public class Fish : Vertebrate 
{
    /// <summary>Fun fact, not all fish can swim backwards! Sharks is one example</summary>
    public bool CanSwimBackwards { get;set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + $", CanSwimBackwards :{CanSwimBackwards}";
    }
}
```

What we've shown here is a simple inheritance model that shows different *properties* being added to the *base class* we can use these to add some *Animals* to a list:

```
List<Animal> myFavouriteAnimals = new List<Animal>();
myFavouriteAnimals.Add(new Animal { Name = "Worm", Eyes = 0 });
myFavouriteAnimals.Add(new Bird { Name = "Hawk", CanFly = true; });
myFavouriteAnimals.Add(new Bird { Name = "Penguin", CanFly = false; });
myFavouriteAnimals.Add(new Fish { Name = "Eel", CanSwimBackwards = true; });
myFavouriteAnimals.Add(new Fish { Name = "Shark", CanSwimBackwards = false; });

foreach(var animal in myFavouriteAnimals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(animal.ToString());
}
```

This would produce the following result:
*Try it out here:* https://dotnetfiddle.net/n6jgHO

```
Worm - Eyes:0
Hawk - Eyes:2, CanFly: True
Penguin - Eyes:2, CanFly: False
Eel - Eyes:2, CanSwimBackwards: True
Shark - Eyes:2, CanSwimBackwards: False
```

There's a little bit of [*syntactic sugar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) in that example but hopefully it helps to explain better scenarios for using inheritance other than just changing the value of an attribute defined in the base class.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing insight, in regards to my predicament
and helping me achieve a broader understanding of the use of interfaces and inheritance.
After thinking about the case and pondering the comments to the original
post I came up with the exact answer for the deck that you also suggested.

As for the example with inheritance It really clarified how to think about inheritance.

I guess I was simply stuck in the mind of "I have to use interface and inheritance"
because that is the theme of the course at the moment".